# Resolution Hat and the end of Winter Bash

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

How can I get the Winter Bash *Resolution* Hat?

In the description it says *Delete 10 comments from 2014 in 2015* but surely Winter Bash ends when 2014 ends?

So if I delete 10 of my old not so helpful or useful comments from 2014, do I get the hat in in Winter Bash 2015? or 2014?

Comment: It ends January 5th, so you can certainly have it for a few days

Comment: Please read the Winder Bash FAQ first http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: The close reason is rather silly and doesn't apply to an honest support request. I've voted to reopen this.

Comment: with so many downvotes, I could get one of those hats by closing/deleting this question (is it *Fear & Loathing*?) Unfortunately, there is a well regarded, and upvoted answer plus removing questions with answers is a no-no, so I can't. NOT FAIR

Comment: @OurManInBananas You don't earn hats on per-site metas. ;)

Comment: should I delete this post?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/faq):

> From December 15th **until January 4th**, you'll be able to earn hats all over the sites!

and

> **After January 4th**, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear.

You'll have a full 4 days to clean up your comments.

Comment: How come the [main page](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) says *"the hats get put back in their boxes on January 5th!"*?  Is this a typo, or should the quote you have say *through* January 4th?

Comment: @iCodez: *until* includes the 4th. At midnight the hats go into the boxes, so on when January 5th starts they are in those boxes and gone.

Comment: @iCodez: in the same FAQ: *After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear*.

Comment: Ok, I see.  I still think "until" should have been "through".  As it is now, it sounds like 00:00 Jan 4 is the cutoff.

Comment: I don't think it does.